# Angular material table sticky not working on header

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use the material table sticky parameter, but for some reason it doesn't work in the table header, it works nicely in the sections below, it just slides in the header when I scroll sideways.

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="table-container">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="select" sticky>
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="px-2 w-50px">
            <div class="pr-3">
              <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" color="warn"
                [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()" [attr.aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
              </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="px-2 w-50px">
            <div class="pr-3">
              <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" color="warn"
                (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                [attr.aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
              </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- name -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="pl-3">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column pl-0 pr-2">
              <div mat-sort-header>
                Name
              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <div>
              <!-- ... -->
            </div>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- ... -->

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

[image]
I invite everything well, everything works since the sticky in the lines below also works.
What can I do to fix the bug so that the sticky works in the header too?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? And also, you mentioned scrolling "sideways". The implementation in your code is meant to have the header stick on vertical scroll, not sure if this is what you intended

Comment: I don't get any errors, yes the scrolling is done sideways, but the first two rows of the column are sticky and so as I scroll the header doesn't stick to it so you can't know what's in the table, that's the problem @Kisinga

Comment: Please provide a screenshot

Comment: I added it to the original post @Kisinga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is sticky column, not sticky header, as much as you can combine both
[Here's an example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xbyenbvbqnx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.ts)

Sticky headers are meant to remain visible when you have multiple table items and you scroll "downwards" or vertically.
Sticky columns remain visible when an individual table column is scrolled "sideways" or horizontally as demonstrated in your screenshot.
Take a look at the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

Answer (score 4):

You need to show more of the code to help you. It seems that the tr rows in the table are missing.
Try adding the value: `"sticky: true"` to the `*matHeaderRowDef` attribute, like this:

```html
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
    (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
</tr>
```

Here a code snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzg5aa?embed=1&file=src/app/table-selection-example.html

Comment: There are also some that are only left out of the shared code, but I wrote that the lines below work with sticky alone in the header does not work.

Comment: I also supplemented my code so it is included. @Andrea Epifano

Comment: Try to do like in the code snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzg5aa?embed=1&file=src/app/table-selection-example.html
With sticky alone seems not work.

Comment: I just have several columns and I just want to set the first two to sticky, which works, it's just that it doesn't work in the header for some reason, and I want to find a way to keep it sticky as a result of scrolling. Since there are a lot of columns in my table that’s why I put the sticky on columns not rows, but it works outside of the header on the column only the header slips. @Andrea Epifano